# django jquery POST development server showing 500 status

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, debugging

I'm trying to get multiple CSV file uploading to django based on `sigurdga / django-jquery-file-upload`

Being very new to javascript and jquery I'm trying to keep the changes to the example code as small as possible.

I successfully changed it to upload general files instead of image files and got it uploading batches of CSV's.

Right now I have a simple but fundamental problem with debugging.

Something I have introduced is causing the Django development server to fail during the POST and return a 500 status - i can see that on the console output from the server.

```
[27/Jan/2014 12:29:31] "POST /banking/new/acount1234/ HTTP/1.1" 500 15103
```

I have debug print statements in various django functions including the relevant `view.form_valid`, `view.form_invalid` `model.save`

I've also added a custom `handler500` to see if I can catch something there.

My problem is that the server is throwing a 500 but I can't work out where to put in some debugging.

So my question is - is there somewhere in Django that I can intercept the URL processing to see why it's throwing a `500`?

The documentation says that with DEBUG=True it shouldn't happen - but I know it does happen because if my `PgSQL` server is stopped it throws 500's on the `GET's`

I can't see a django debug page as the `js` page doesn't give me any status, and I'm not familiar enough to customise it.

I'd have expected the control flow to end up in my `form_invalid` but it doesn't.

I should add that based on the example I am using the generic `CBV` `CreateView` so maybe that is generating the `500` and perhaps I should crib the source code for that and create my own view code based on it that I can then instrument with `print's`

**UPDATE**

As I'm using the generic `CBVs`, there's a lot of stuff hidden behind the scenes.

The only way I found to debug it was to actually copy the django source for CreateView and various super-classes to my own source file temporarily and put pdb breakpoints in.

In summary I'd assumed I could use the off the shelf package to upload a file and add the additional fields for my model by overriding `form_valid` in the view or `save` in the `Model`.

However `CreateView` checks that the object data is valid BEFORE I got access to it so it threw an exception for any fields that were `blank=False` or `null-False`.

I changed my model to allow `Null` and `Blank` on all but the file and it allowed it through so that I could populate them in `form_valid`.

Subsequently it threw another `500` because of an exception in my `CSV` processing with a non-ascii character in an upload file.

There must be an easier way to debug stuff where client side scripting and `JSON` hide the simple server page response

Comment: You can use your browser's developer tools to see the full Django error page.

Comment: How do I do that (in `Chrome`)?

Comment: With the Chrome developer tools, as I said. There are plenty of guides in using them on the web.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `DEBUG = True` then you should be able to see the stack trace with all the information you want. But because you are doing an AJAX request, you can see the result by opening developer tools (or firebug), going to the network tab and seeing the response there. If you are using Chrome you should be able to preview the page right there and see the error.

Other than that, you can simply use `ipdb` and add a breakpoint anywhere in your code, typically in your view method. Install using pip and add this line:

`python
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`

Comment: I'd expect a stack trace but there's nothing - just the console log entry I posted. So I don't know where to start debugging. I assume that the 500 report is coming from runserver but if I don't know where the exception is and I don't have a stack trace where do I set my breakpoint?

Comment: I don't think it is getting as far as my views or forms code. Where can i get in earlier in the process of the server dealing with the POST so I can see where it's going wrong?

Comment: OK you can see the 500 from runserver console but you should see stack trace on browser as well. That will have a lot more information. It could be that you have a DB error and even before you hit the view django is throwing an exception, but even in that case there should be some log when `DEBUG = True`

Comment: My webpage is off-the shelf `JQuery` and it's complex, - I'm using `django-jquery-file-upload` and it does not display the development server stacktrace. I don't really understand why the server is returning a `500` - I thought that was inhibited when `DEBUG=True`